# Example code for a comment parser

Tags: php, codeigniter

Anyone know of any sample php (ideally codeigniter) code for parsing user submitted comments. TO remove profanity and HTML tags etc?

Comment: Surely CodeIgniter has an easy component for escaping HTML, right? Word filter should be trivial enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to get rid of any html submitted. You can use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to escape the tags if you just want to ensure that no html is displayed in the comments - as per Matchu's example, less unintended effects will happen with it than with strip_tags.

For a word filter, depending on how indepth you want to go, there are many examples on the web, from [simple](http://www.offsky.com/software/badword.txt) to [complex](http://www.bitrepository.com/advanced-word-filter.html). Here's the code from Jake Olefsky's example (the simple one linked previously):

```
<?
//This is totally free to use by anyone for any purpose.

// BadWordFilter
// This function does all the work. If $replace is 1 it will replace all bad words
// with the wildcard replacements.  If $replace is 0 it will not replace anything.
// In either case, it will return 1 if it found bad words or 0 otherwise.
// Be sure to fill the $bads array with the bad words you want filtered.
function BadWordFilter(&$text, $replace)
{
    //fill this array with the bad words you want to filter and their replacements
    $bads = array (
        array("butt","b***"),
        array("poop","p***"),
        array("crap","c***")
    );

    if($replace==1) {                               //we are replacing
        $remember = $text;

        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($bads);$i++) {           //go through each bad word
            $text = eregi_replace($bads[$i][0],$bads[$i][5],$text); //replace it
        }

        if($remember!=$text) return 1;              //if there are any changes, return 1

    } else {                                        //we are just checking

        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($bads);$i++) {           //go through each bad word
            if(eregi($bads[$i][0],$text)) return 1; //if we find any, return 1
        }   

    }
}

//this will replace all bad words with their replacements. $any is 1 if it found any
$any = BadWordFilter($wordsToFilter,1); 

//this will not repace any bad words. $any is 1 if it found any
$any = BadWordFilter($wordsToFilter,0); 

?>
```

Many more examples of this can be [found easily](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=php+word+filter) on the web.

Comment: I vote for htmlspecialchars instead, to ensure that nothing like "Hello <world>!" is mistaken for HTML.

Comment: If Alex wants to escape them and not remove them, then I agree, htmlspecialchars is better.

Comment: Depends what "remove" means :)

Comment: That's true - the intent is ambiguous :)

Comment: I want to remove any html, effectively i am trying to take whatever is entered by the user and turn it into plain text. So any HTML i want to delete completely rather than just escape.